# Tradeoff between using this and inline code in constructor

Tags: java, performance, constructor, this, overloading

One reason why invoking overloaded constructors through this() can be useful is that it can prevent the unnecessary duplication of code.In many cases, reducing duplicate code decreases the time it takes to load your class because often the object code is smaller. This is especially important for programs delivered via the Internet in which load times are an issue.

However, you need to be careful. Constructors that call this() will execute a bit slower than those that contain all of their initialization code inline. This is because the call and return mechanism used when the second constructor is invoked adds overhead. If your class will be used to create only a handful of objects, or if the constructors in the class that
call this() will be seldom used, then this decrease in run-time performance is probably insignificant.

**How time taken for loading of class is smaller?
and
What should be the points of trade-off between using this in constructor and using inline code ?**

Comment: Not really controversial here. Write your code for readability and maintenance, not theoretical performance benefits. That means you write the code once and use `this()` to invoke it where needed.

Comment: Do you have a performance problem? Does repeating the code, thus making it harder to maintain, solve it?

Comment: Performance is completely irrelevant. Use the most maintainable code. Duplications in the code means that there is a big chance that when you need to make a change, you'll forget to do it everywhere the code is duplicated.

Comment: Trade-off between 3 milliseconds and 2 kilobytes (where JVM itself will take tens of megabytes)... I really cannot see any problem here - this is insignificant. And if performance/memory usage are that critical, you wouldn't use Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a brilliantly typical case of premature optimization. Nobody thinks about performance when eliminating duplication, they just think about deleting several code paths that essentially do the same thing while cluttering the code base and giving opportunities for divergence between these code paths.

Conclusion: don't worry about such petty things, just write good and concise code. Duplication will hurt your system a thousand times more than a method call will hurt your performance.